Any of the following conditions "IS" or "ARE"?
I'm writing technical requirements for one of the projects and the format is typically as follows.
The ZZZ application shall display [x] when any of the following conditions is met:

[y] is TRUE
[z] is FALSE

Is this a proper form, or should it be "any of the following conditions are" or "any of the following condition is", or the original format is correct?
The intent is that meeting any one of the conditions is enough to display [x] hence why I write it as "any of...is".
